# Starting my react native script,It is showing an Error: something Is already running on port 3000

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When i try to run it on different port like 3001,3002,etc..,It is refused to connect to localhost server.I tried to find what is running on that port but i am not able to see any port number named as 3000 when i run netstat.I tried changing port number in package.json also but it didnt help.

*How about that error?*

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information to help, worst case you restart server

Comment: I tried to restart it as well,but it didnt help

Comment: Try an other port in your project's config file?

Comment: Tried..It starts at another port but localhost refused to connect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After some research, the easiest way is doing the following steps.
(It works fine on Windows 10):

1. Open Task manager (press CTRL+ALT+DELETE)
2. Select the 'Processes tab'
3. Search for 'Node.js: Server-side JavaScript'
4. Select it and click on 'End task' button

Now you can run 'npm start'.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

change code which is in **package.json**。

**original：**
*"start": "concurrently "cross-env BROWSER=none craco start" "wait-on http://localhost:4000 && electron ."",*

**after change**：
*"start": "concurrently "cross-env port=4000 BROWSER=none craco start" "wait-on http://localhost:4000 && electron ."",*

Just add “port=4000”